# Run powershell command from C# application

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to run the following powershell commands from my C# application:

```
Enter-PSSession –ComputerName fedsrv01.domain.local

Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
```

I found some information on the Powershell Class but struggling to achieve what I want due to my lack of experience.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=pscore-6.2.0

This is what I have so far:

I have added the assembly and referenced system.management.automation

```
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{

     //powershell.AddCommand("get-process");
     powershell.AddCommand("Enter-PSSession -ComputerName fedsrv01.domain.local");


     powershell.Invoke();
}
```

I get an error saying, `'The term 'Enter-PSSession -ComputerName fedsrv01.domain.local' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

if I use: `powershell.AddCommand("get-process")` it executes fine.

If I launch Powershell on the same PC and enter, `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName fedsrv01.domain.local` it works fine.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Jono

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell commands from C# 'the term is not recognizes as cmdlet'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272931/powershell-commands-from-c-sharp-the-term-is-not-recognizes-as-cmdlet)

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling your application as x64. If it is compiled as x86 platform then it will be using the virtualized System32 dir so the function you require may not exist.

[Powershell commands from C# 'the term is not recognizes as cmdlet'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272931/powershell-commands-from-c-sharp-the-term-is-not-recognizes-as-cmdlet)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after more research into the PowerShell class I now realise that you have to add the parameters separately using the .addparameter method.
.addcommand is just for the PowerShell commands. It now makes sense why I got the error saying the command could not be found. It was assuming the entire string was a command.
Problem solved!

Jono